# ARKit/ARFoundation camera freezes after one second

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, arkit, ipados, ar-foundation

1. I setup boilerplate ARFoundation project in Unity.
2. I check *ARKit* box in *Project settings > XR Plug-in Management > iOS*.
3. In *Player > Other Settings* I check *Requires ARKit support*
4. Build in Unity, then install into iPad through XCode.

App starts, popup for camera permission appears, camera is working for 1-2 seconds then freezes. Happens every time I open my app. No errors in logs.

- Unity version: 2021.3.10f
- iPad Pro 11" 2021 with iPadOS v.15.6
- Xcode version: 13.3.1

Comment: anything in the xcode console?

Comment: "No errors in logs"

Comment: if there is no messages at all then this seems to be a bug. You might try to check if you have the newest version of ARFoundation and then file a bug report.

Comment: There are messages, but only about successfully booting up application - nothing that would point in any direction about potential problem

Answer (score 3):

I have encountered this issue as well, the fix I did was to update the ar foundation so the version is the same as the Ar kit (I was only updating the ar kit, and missed updating the ar foundation when this issue appears).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I met exactly the same situation before. No error logs, no app crash, but the camera screen freezes.

After updating AR Foundation, AR Kit, AR Core to same version (4.1.12), the issue has been fixed.

Romi's solution still works!